# Periodic Sync never triggering

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Im using `SyncAdapter` for some server client synchronization. In the [official android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html) it is mentioned that there are different methods to trigger a sync.

### **1 Run the Sync Adapter When Server Data Changes**

You simply call:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, null);
```

When server data changes (on GCM for example).

### **2 Run the Sync Adapter When Content Provider Data Changes**

Simply use a `ContentObserver`

```
public class TableObserver extends ContentObserver {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri changeUri) {
        ContentResolver.requestSync(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, null);
    }
}
```

### **3 Run the Sync Adapter After a Network Message**

Do the following:

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, true)
```

Now everytime when there is an open TCP/IP connection the `SyncAdapter` is triggered to perform the sync.

### **4 Run the Sync Adapter Periodically**

This is for me the important and interesting part. For that you simply have to do this (at least this is written in the developers guide):

```
public static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60L;
public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 60L;
public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL = SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            ACCOUNT,
            AUTHORITY,
            Bundle.EMPTY,
            SYNC_INTERVAL);
```

### **Now to the problem**

Solution 1, 2 and 3 are working perfectly as they should. The periodical sync does not. If i just do what is descriped under point 4 the synchronization is never triggered (yes i did enable the auomatic synchronisation in the system settings of my android device).

If i do the following:

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), 3600);
```

The `SyncAdapter` sync refresh is called every minute (it should be every hour / 3600 seconds = 1 hour). If i do the following:

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), 3600);
```

The sync is only triggered once at creation time and after that never again. Yes, as i mentioned already, the automatic sync in the android devices settings is enabled.

Triggering the sync manually for my app in the android device settings accountmanager is working fine.

**So why does the periodic sync does not work?**

I tested on Nexus 4 with Android 6.0, On Galaxy Ace with Android 4.4 and on Galaxy S3 Mini with Android 4.1. All devices are not syncing periodically.

Comment: "sync refresh is called every minute" <- Did you verify, that you are not requesting a manual sync at some other place in the app?

Comment: Yes - verified. It is possible that the periodic sync works when i set `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContentProviderMeasure.AUTHORITY, true);` but i cant actually test it because with this option set to true the sync is triggered ALWAYS when there is an open TCP/IP connection what is... actually... always the case. And if i disable mobile data then ofcourse no sync would be triggered at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented **Periodic Sync** for `Calendar` **AUTHORITY**.

**Add** `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />` permission in Manifest file.

Add below method for Sync:

```
public void syncAllAccountsPeriodically(Context contextAct, long seconds) throws Exception {
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(contextAct);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String accountName = "";
    String accountType = "";
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        accountName = account.name;
        accountType = account.type;
        break;
    }

    Account a = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(a, "com.android.calendar", new Bundle(), seconds*1000);
}
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I know it is an old post, but why do you multiply the seconds with factor 1000? According to the documentation the parameter should be passed in seconds. So if you had milliSeconds you would divide by 1000 or for minutes you would multiply with 60.
My current code looks basically like yours but my periodicSync triggers only once when creating it and never again after that. The only difference is the *1000